# Is the bond between wizard and wand for Harry still there after Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

Through many questions here, we can see a debate that Harry's wand chose him partly because of the affinity between the Horcrux-like part of Voldemort which resides within Harry at the point of purchase, back in Philosopher's Stone. Theoretically, had Harry not had Voldemort's fragment inside him, he may have had a different wand choose him.

My question being: now that Harry is Voldemort-free, does the same bond exist between Harry and the wand? Should the wand reject Harry at all due to a differing of the soul[s] that once occupied the body?

Comment: Edit made to remove link to movie.

Comment: I think this is a good question with a good answer, but this is not reflected in the upvotes for either. Are people being more critical lately? Is the site overrun with questions? Is there less activity, or is it all elsewhere? Been wondering for a while now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Probably

**Wands have a certain loyalty to those who have wielded them**. Any wand but the Elder Wand will possess at least some degree of attachment to its previous owner, merely because of their time wielding it, as indicated in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/could-harry-potter-have-given-draco-malfoys-wand-back/25288#25288). Given that Harry had wielded his wand for seven years, it probably was fairly attached to him.

In addition, phoenix-feather wands are choosy about about whom they allow to wield them.

[According to Pottermore](http://web.archive.org/web/20160101083825/http://lady-slytherin-forever.tumblr.com/post/8977640199/wand-cores-off-of-pottermore):

> Phoenix feather wands are always the pickiest when it comes to
>   potential owners, for the creature from which they are taken is one of
>   the most independent and detached in the world. These wands are the
>   hardest to tame and to personalise, and their allegiance is usually
>   hard won.

**While Harry may have been imbued with certain qualities from the presence of Voldemort's soul, the majority of his personality was diametrically opposed to that of Voldemort.** As mentioned [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60647/51379), we don't really know exactly why Harry's wand picked him. It probably had something to do with Voldemort's connection to him, but it may not have. For example, perhaps the feather was inclined to choose wizards with great innate power, which both Harry and Voldemort possessed.

From the same Pottermore source, of *unicorn-hair* wands:

> They are the most faithful of all wands, and usually remain strongly
>   attached to their first owner, irrespective of whether he or she was
>   an accomplished witch or wizard.

This seems to indicate that *other* wands care about how powerful a witch or wizard is, which would have been a good reason to choose Harry or Voldemort.

In any case, if Harry's personal qualities influenced the wand to choose him, those still existed after the part of Voldemort within him was destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, the bond between Harry and his wand seems very intact.

When Harry repairs his wand after the battle when the piece of the Dark Lord’s soul is gone, red sparks fly out of it, and he says it feels like if his wand and his hand were rejoicing at their reunion.

> “He laid the broken wand upon the Headmaster’s desk, touched it with the very tip of the Elder Wand and said, *‘Reparo.’*
>
> As his wand resealed, red sparks flew out of its end. Harry knew that he had succeeded. He picked up the holly and phoenix wand, and felt a sudden warmth in his fingers, as though wand and hand were rejoicing at their reunion.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

This seems like a very strong indication that Harry and his wand are still bonded.

## In addition, it *should* be - Harry’s personality remains the same.

As well as the evidence we see when Harry fixed his wand, it seems very likely that Harry’s wand would still be bonded with him after he loses the piece of the Dark Lord’s soul in him, since he’s still basically the same. Though he had that soul piece when his wand chose him and for seven years since then, the essentials of who Harry is wasn’t changed by the presence of the soul piece. J.K. Rowling confirmed in an interview that Harry himself wasn’t ‘contaminated’ by having it.

> JKR: And so this part of it flies off, and attaches to the only living thing in the room. A part of it flees in the very-close-to-death limbo state that Voldemort then goes on and exists in. I suppose it’s very close to being a Horcrux, but Harry did not become an evil object. He didn’t have curses upon him that the other Horcruxes had. He himself was not contaminated by carrying this bit of parasitic soul. The only time he ever felt it stirring and moving was in Order of the Phoenix, when he himself goes through a very dark time. 
> <sub><sup>*[- PotterCast (Dec 23, 2007)](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/12/23/transcript-of-part-1-of-pottercast-s-jk-rowling-interview/)*</sup></sub>

Since having the soul piece gone wouldn’t change who he is, except in very small ways like removing his ability to speak Parseltongue, his wand shouldn’t have much reason to reject him.